Vite path aliases in imported submodule
I have a project, let's call it parent, which depends on a submodule sub.
parent/  
│ vite.config.js
│ package.json
│ src/
│ ...
│
└───sub/
    │ vite.config.js
    │ package.json
    │ src/
    │ │ inner-import.js
    │ │ main-file.js
    │ └─── ...
    │      
    └───...


Both parent and sub have individual vite.config.js files
// parent/vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@src": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      "sub": path.resolve(__dirname, "./sub"),
    },
  },
  test: {
    exclude: [
      ...configDefaults.exclude,
      "sub/**"  // Don't run tests in submodule code
    ]
  }
});



and
// parent/sub/vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@src": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    }
  },
  ...
})


sub also has the following fields in its package.json.
// parent/sub/package.json
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "main": "src/main-file.js",
  ...


parent has installed sub as evident in parent's `package.json``
// parent/package.json
   "dependencies": {  
     ...
     "sub": "file:sub",
     ...


When importing sub (import { foobar } from "sub") in a test in parent and testing with npx vitest, I get the following error,
Failed to resolve import "@src/inner-import.js" from "sub/src/main-file.js". Does the file exist?

(where inner-import.js is some file needed by sub/src/main-file.js.)


A couple caveats:

I can't build and then import sub because I'll need hot reloading in both parent and sub during development
I don't wish to change any path aliasing because @src -> ./src is an org-wide convention.



In short the question is, how do I use vite's path aliasing in nested modules?
